# Where are operators for built-in Godot types defined?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Many of the built-in Godot types (Vector2, Rect2, etc.) support operators (+/-/*, etc.) that are not documented along with the type. Where can I find information about the supported operators and their semantics for all types?

If there is no documentation available, where in the Godot source code can the bindings for these operators be found?

The specific case I am interested in right now is converting a Rect2 to bool as part of an if statement, i.e.,

```
func my_func(area: Rect2):
    if area:
        # When do I get here?
        # Is this equivalent to if !area.has_no_area()?
```

Comment: It should be under `~/modules/gdscript`, but GDScript is a really stripped-down version of Python, and a lot of stuff must be done explicitly. Why not just write `if !area.has_no_area():`?

Comment: @Dúthomhas In that case mostly it's the double negative that bothers me. But it prompted the question of where things such as the Vector2 multiplication operator are documented.

Comment: Yeah, they’re not really documented. You just have to try it or browse the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where can I find information about the supported operators and their semantics for all types?
>
> If there is no documentation available, where in the Godot source code can the bindings for these operators be found?

For Godot 3.x, the only complete canonical source is the source code for Variant. The file [variant_op.cpp](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.x/core/variant_op.cpp) to be more precise.

However, the documentation for Godot 4.0 already includes the operators on the class pages.

---

> The specific case I am interested in right now is converting a Rect2 to bool as part of an if statement, i.e.,
>
> ```
> func my_func(area: Rect2):
>     if area:
>         # When do I get here?
>         # Is this equivalent to if !area.has_no_area()?
> ```

*Note: this is not an operator.*

Conversion to bool used here is handled by the [`booleanize`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.x/core/variant_op.cpp#L152-L154) method, which delegate to [`is_zero`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.x/core/variant.cpp#L665) (as in zeroed memory). In general, an uninitialized variable converts to false.

For `Rect2` that means that when position is zero (`(0,0)`) and size is zero (`(0,0)`), the `Rect2` will convert to false, anything else converts to true.

Comment: I was thinking along the line of C++ conversion operators, but I see godot handles it differently. Glad to see the documentation improving for 4.0!